# Do capture lists of inner closures need to redeclare `self` as `weak` or `unowned`?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, unowned-references

If I have a closure passed to a function like this:

```
 someFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in
     anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in 
         self?.doSomething()
     }
 }
```

If I declare self as `[weak self]` in `someFunctionWithTrailingClosure`'s capture list without redeclaring it as `weak` again in the capture list of `anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure` `self` is already becoming an `Optional` type but is it also becoming a `weak` reference as well?

Thanks!

Comment: This is easily verified empirically. Yes, `self` in the closure of `anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure` is both optional and `weak`.

Comment: The optional part is easily verifiable but how can I verify that its also weak?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `[weak self]` in `anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure` is not needed.

You can empirically test this:

```swift
class Experiment {
    func someFunctionWithTrailingClosure(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("starting", #function)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            closure()
            print("finishing", #function)
        }
    }

    func anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("starting", #function)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            closure()
            print("finishing", #function)
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print(#function)
    }

    func testCompletionHandlers() {
        someFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in
            self?.anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure { // [weak self] in
                self?.doSomething()
            }
        }
    }

    // go ahead and add `deinit`, so I can see when this is deallocated

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

And then:

```swift
func performExperiment() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let obj = Experiment()

        obj.testCompletionHandlers()

        // sleep long enough for `anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure` to start, but not yet call its completion handler

        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.5)
    }
}
```

If you do this, you will see that `doSomething` is never called and that `deinit` is called before `anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure` calls its closure.

That having been said, I might still be inclined to use the `[weak self]` syntax on `anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure` to make my intent explicit.

Answer (score 12):

TL;DR

Although using `[weak self]` once in the *outer* block is fine (EX1), if you change this reference to strong (e.g. `guard let self = self`), you'll need a `[weak self]` in the inner block as well (EX3).

Also using `[weak self]` only once on the *inner* block is typically an error (EX2_B). Unfortunately, this is a common mistake to make when refactoring code, and can be hard-to-spot when it is made.

---

A good rule of thumb is to always use `weak` if the object is strong immediately outside of the closure.

Examples that don't retain `self` (i.e. typically these are the "good" scenarios):

```
// EX1
fn { [weak self] in
  self?.foo() 
}
```

```
// EX2
fn { [weak self] in 
  fn2 {
    self?.foo()
  }
}
// self is weak inside fn, thus adding an extra `[weak self]` inside fn2 is unnecessary
```

```
// EX3
fn { [weak self] in 
  guard let self = self else { return }
  fn2 { [weak self] in
    self?.foo()
  }
}
```

Examples that DO retain `self` (i.e. typically the "bad" scenarios):

```
// EX1_B
fn {
  self.foo()
}
// fn retains self
```

```
// EX2_B
fn {
  fn2 { [weak self] in
    self.foo()
  }
}
// fn retains self (this is a common, hard-to-spot mistake)
```

```
// EX3_B
fn { [weak self] in 
  guard let self = self else { return }
  fn2 {
    self.foo()
  }
}
// fn2 retains self
```

---

As [Hamish alludes to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992442/35690), there are two main reasons `weak` is useful:

1. To prevent retain cycles.
2. To prevent objects living longer than they should be.

### More on #2 (preventing long lived objects)

In [Rob's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751221/35690), the function is not retaining the closure (beyond dispatch_async which is all but guaranteed to fire the closure at some point in the future), thus you'll never end up with a retain cycle. So using `weak` in this case, then, is to prevent #2 from happening.

As Hamish mentions, weak is not actually needed in this example to prevent retain cycles, as there are no retain cycles. `weak`, in this case, is used to prevent an object living longer than needed. It depends entirely on your use-case as to when you consider an object living longer than needed. Thus there are times when you would want to use `weak` only outside (EX2), and other times when you would want to use the `weak` outer, `strong` inner, `weak` inner dance (EX3), for example.

### More on #1 (preventing retain cycles)

To examine the retain cycle problem, let's say a function is storing a reference to the block (i.e. heap) instead of referencing the function directly (i.e. stack). Many times we don't know the internals of a class/function, so it's safer to assume that the function *is* retaining the block.

Now you can easily create a retain cycle using `weak` outer, and only using `strong` inner (EX3_B):

```
public class CaptureListExperiment {

    public init() {

    }

    var _someFunctionWithTrailingClosure: (() -> ())?
    var _anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure: (() -> ())?

    func someFunctionWithTrailingClosure(closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("starting someFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        _someFunctionWithTrailingClosure = closure

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            self?._someFunctionWithTrailingClosure!()
            print("finishing someFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        }
    }

    func anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure(closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("starting anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        _anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure = closure

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            self?._anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure!()
            print("finishing anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("doSomething")
    }

    public func testCompletionHandlers() {
        someFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure { // [weak self] in
                self.doSomething()
            }
        }
    }

    // go ahead and add `deinit`, so I can see when this is deallocated

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

func performExperiment() {

    let obj = CaptureListExperiment()

    obj.testCompletionHandlers()
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.3)
}

performExperiment()

/* Output:

starting someFunctionWithTrailingClosure
starting anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure
finishing someFunctionWithTrailingClosure
doSomething
finishing anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure
*/
```

Notice that `deinit` is not called, since a retain cycle was created.

This could be fixed by either removing the `strong` reference (EX2):

```
public func testCompletionHandlers() {
    someFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in
        //guard let self = self else { return }
        self?.anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure { // [weak self] in
            self?.doSomething()
        }
    }
}
```

Or using the weak/strong/weak dance (EX3):

```
public func testCompletionHandlers() {
    someFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in
            self?.doSomething()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for detailed info! Very helpful! However, I am confused on your "EX2_B", which you mentioned "fn retains self (this is a common, hard-to-spot mistake)". But, in "EX2_B", I only observe self is used in fn2 and not fn. Do you mind to explain more? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Updated for Swift 4.2:

```
public class CaptureListExperiment {

    public init() {

    }

    func someFunctionWithTrailingClosure(closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("starting someFunctionWithTrailingClosure")

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            closure()
            print("finishing someFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        }
    }

    func anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure(closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("starting anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure")

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            closure()
            print("finishing anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("doSomething")
    }

    public func testCompletionHandlers() {
        someFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure { // [weak self] in
                self.doSomething()
            }
        }
    }

    // go ahead and add `deinit`, so I can see when this is deallocated

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

try it Playgorund:

```
func performExperiment() {

    let obj = CaptureListExperiment()

    obj.testCompletionHandlers()
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.3)
}

performExperiment()
```