# Where does the weak self go?

Tags: swift, weak-references

I often do this,

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
   beep()
}
```

and in one app we often do this

```
tickle.fresh(){
    msg in
    paint()
}
```

but if you do *this*

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
   tickle.fresh(){
      msg in
      paint()
   }
}
```

of course you have to do *this*

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { [weak self] _ in
   tickle.fresh(){
      msg in
      self?.paint()
   }
}
```

or, maybe *this*

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
   tickle.fresh(){
      [weak self] msg in
      self?.paint()
   }
}
```

*or maybe this*

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { [weak self] _ in
   tickle.fresh(){
      [weak self] msg in
      self?.paint()
   }
}
```

## W T H should we do?

All three suggestions *seem* to work perfectly. What's the full depth of meaning here? And which should one do? Is a strong reference to a weak reference, a weak or strong reference? To be or not to be?  That's the question!

Answer (score 244, accepted):

First of all, note that you generally don't need to worry about retain cycles with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`, as the closure will be executed at *some* point. Therefore whether or not you weakly capture `self`, you won't be creating a permanent retain cycle (assuming that `tickle.fresh` also doesn't).

Whether or not you put a `[weak self]` capture list on the outer `asyncAfter` closure depends entirely on whether you want `self` to be retained until the closure is called (after the time you set). If you don't need `self` to remain alive until the closure is called, put `[weak self]` in, if you do, then don't put it in.

Whether or not you put a `[weak self]` on the inner closure (the one passed to `tickle.fresh`) depends on whether you've already weakly captured `self` in the outer closure. If you haven't, then you can put `[weak self]` in order to prevent the inner closure from retaining it. If however, the outer closure has already weakly captured `self`, then the inner closure will *already* have a weak reference to `self`, thus adding `[weak self]` to the inner closure will have no effect.

So, to summarise:

---

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
   tickle.fresh { msg in
      self.paint()
   }
}
```

`self` will be retained by both the outer and inner closure.

---

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
   tickle.fresh { msg in
      self?.paint()
   }
}
```

`self` will not be retained by either closure.

---

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
   tickle.fresh { [weak self] msg in
      self?.paint()
   }
}
```

Same as the above, the additional `[weak self]` for the inner closure has no effect, as `self` is already weakly captured by the outer closure.

---

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
   tickle.fresh { [weak self] msg in
      self?.paint()
   }
}
```

`self` will be retained by the outer closure, but not the inner closure.

---

Of course, it might be that you don't want `self` to be retained by the outer closure, but you *do* want it to be retained by the inner closure. In such cases, you can declare a local variable in the outer closure in order to hold a strong reference to `self`, when you can then capture in the inner closure:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
   guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
   tickle.fresh { msg in
      strongSelf.paint()
   }
}
```

Now, `self` won't be kept alive by the outer closure, but once it's called, if `self` still exists, it will be kept alive by the inner closure until that closure has been deallocated.

---

In response to:

> Is a strong reference to a weak reference, a weak or strong reference?

Weak references are implemented as optionals, which are value types. Therefore you cannot *directly* have a strong reference to one – instead you first have to unwrap it, and then take a strong reference to the underlying instance. In this case you're simply dealing with a strong reference (exactly like my example above with `strongSelf`).

However, if a weak reference is *boxed* (this happens with closure capture – the value type will be put into a heap-allocated box) – then you can indeed have a strong reference to that box. The effect of this is equivalent to a weak reference to the original instance, you just have an invisible bit of extra indirection.

In fact, this is *exactly* what happens in the example where the outer closure weakly captures `self` and the inner closure 'strongly captures' that weak reference. The effect is that neither closure retains `self`.

Comment: @JoeBlow It means that `self` will be kept alive by the outer closure, but once it has been executed, it could be deallocated *before* the inner closure gets executed (assuming that it's executed asynchronously). And in the final example, I'm using optional binding with `guard let`, which unwraps the weak `self`, giving me a strong reference to it :)

Comment: @JoeBlow Sure, there's no harm in using both – although as I say, the inner `[weak self]` is unnecessary if the outer closure captures `self` weakly.

Comment: Your note has been noted @JoeBlow :) I added a response to your question "*Is a strong reference to a weak reference, a weak or strong reference?*" late last night btw, don't know whether you saw it or not. The answer is it can be either – depending on how you're taking the strong reference to the weak reference.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Really nice and clear answer, is there any documentation related to these ARC inner closures  concepts?

Comment: Your headline "First of all, note that you generally don't need to worry about retain cycles with " is misleading. With dispatchQueues it's NEVER a concern of 'retain cycles' The concern is mainly about 'strong references', 'abandoned memory', basically an object that is referenced from a root/global object. Roots/globals are like GCD or runloop. e.g. with Runloop and (repeating) timers. The runloop is never releasing `self` its target. `self` doesn't have a reference back to the runloop. Hence it never gets deallocated. (1/2)

Comment: The memory graph for abandoned memory is a **one** way linear graph that goes all the way back to a root object. For retains cycles is either a cycle or a '**two** way' line in isolation. For more see [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/?time=1952). Also see [How can I create a reference cycle using dispatchQueues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061092/how-can-i-create-a-reference-cycle-using-dispatchqueues) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261915/does-xcode-memory-graph-offer-any-smart-visual-indicators-for-strong-references?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I have to add a caveat to the notion that, when using `asyncAfter`, a weakification is in all cases not necessary. I haven't tried it lately, but there was a time when UIViewController instances died as soon as they were removed from the view hierarchy, leading to a crash when accessing them asynchronously. Weakification mitigated this. To be fair, it probably was a bug in UIKit's memory management.