# Swift closure "partial apply forwarder"

Tags: ios, swift

I did a quick testing and am trying to pass a closure as function argument, but notice some kind of "exception".  The app is not crashing but the offending line generating a crash report.

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    typealias MapTouchHandler = (String) -> Void

    var mapTouchHandlers = Array<MapTouchHandler>()

    @IBAction func tapGestureAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            for handler in mapTouchHandlers {

                // This line produces this: "0x000000010c8f8a00 Mediator`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in Swift.String) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned Swift.String) -> () at MapViewController.swift"

                handler("tap recognized")
            }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }



     func subscribeMapTouchEvent(mapTouchHandler: @escaping MapTouchHandler) {

           // This line produce this: "0x000000010c8ff910 Mediator`partial apply forwarder with unmangled suffix ".16" at Mediator.swift"

            mapTouchHandlers.append(mapTouchHandler)
    }
}
```

**Mediator class**

```
import UIKit

class Mediator {

    var mapViewController: MapViewController? {
        didSet {
            mapViewController?.subscribeMapTouchEvent(mapTouchHandler: self.handleTouchEvent(str:))
        }
    }

    private func handleTouchEvent(str: String) {
        print(str)
    }
}
```

Appreciate any insight to solve this issue.

Comment: Does the app crash or not?

Comment: The app does not crash

Comment: Then what does "offending line generating a crash report" mean? Is it a compiler error/warning, a runtime error/warning, or what?

Comment: I am a bit lost as well, app is not crashing but in hockey app it is producing a crash report: `Thread 0 Crashed: partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned __C.CGPoint, @owned [__ObjC.MGLFeature]) -> () to @callee_owned (@in (__C.CGPoint, [__ObjC.MGLFeature])) -> (@out ()) (MapViewController.swift:0)`

Comment: If I put breakpoint on `mapTouchHandlers.append(mapTouchHandler)`, in debugger I can see `mapTouchHandler = (() -> () 0x000000010ee7a910 Mediator partial apply forwarder with unmangled suffix ".16" at Mediator.swift` .  And breakpoint on  `handler("tap recognized")` shows `handler = (() -> ()) 0x000000010ee73a00 Mediator partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in Swift.String) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned Swift.String) -> () at MapViewController.swift`

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring "self" in a block i recommend you to use weak self, thus you can avoid retain cycle, memory leak and crash.

Example,

```
getAsynchronousData { [weak self] data in
    guard let self = self else { return }

    self.yourProperty = data 
}
```

Comment: According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992442/2610888  and this https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/functional-programming-closure-reference-cycle-and-fix-f42cc53c6213 you do not need to add the capture list with weak self when using DispatchQueue.main.async as no retain cycles are created

Comment: this example is misleading about capturing self within a block because you shouldn't be cautious about `self` in dispatch queues.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this Q&A from [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6078). Tips for you: find the variable that maybe `nil` and have something to do with `Objective-C` code. I fixed the bug in mine. Good luck!