# Broadcast 'weak self' to escaping block

Tags: swift, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

How capturing rules work if being inside some block we broadcast weakly captured object (`self` for example) to the next escaping block?

```
myBlock = { [weak self] in
    ...
    nextBlock() { [weak self] in // is it necessary if `weak self` already captured in parent block?
        ...
    }
}
```

If we don't write `[weak self]` in the child block, does `self` become strongly captured or remains weak?

Comment: You only need `[weak self]` in the outer capture list – compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/41991467/2976878 (dupe?)