# Do we need to repeat `guard let self = self else { return }` inside each nested closure to keep strong self?

Tags: swift

I need to keep strong self inside my inner clousures.
I know that it's enough to declare `[weak self]` only once for outer closure.

But what about `guard let self = self else { return }`, is it enough to declare it once for outer closure also? Do we have any edge cases here ?

```
  apiManager.doSomething(user: user) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            self.storageManager.doSomething(user: user) { result in
                // guard let self = self else { return } <- DO WE NEED IT HERE ?
                self.doSomething()
            }
        }
```

Seems like language analyser says NO - one declaration is enough , but want to be sure.

Comment: U need 2, sometimes, based on the solid example provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/62352667/72437 . The safest approach, is to use 2, as those edge case is very hard to spot later on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, one is enough.
If you write

```
guard let self = self else { return }
```

you'll create a *new* local variable that will hold a strong reference to the *outside* weak self.

It's the same as writing

```
guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
```

and then use `strongSelf` for the rest of the block.

Comment: Yes, also including the nested blocks. In that case i personally would prefer `strongSelf`, because it's more exhaustive.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, regarding retain cycles. But technically this will depend on how and how log the closure is being stored.

Comment: As of Swift 5.8 there are two additional  simplifications: 1. it's possible now to write `guard let self else { return }`, 2. There is no need of explicitly writing `self.` inside the closure. Maybe worth an edit (?)

Answer (score 17):

### Update Swift 5.7

You don't need a new guard in `doSomething(user:)`, when that method works synchronously.
With Swift 5.7, you can use the rewrite syntax `guard let self else`

```swift
apiManager.doSomething(user: user) { [weak self] result in
  guard let self else { return }

  self.storageManager.doSomething(user: user) { result in
      // You don't a new guard here, when doSomething works synchronously
      self.doSomething()
  }
}
```

But, when your `guard` only returns, than you could also write it so:
Same behaviour.

```swift
apiManager.doSomething(user: user) { [weak self] _ in
  self?.storageManager.doSomething(user: user) { _ in
      self?.doSomething()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, in short you do not need that. If you outer closure uses `[weak self]` then you should not worry about the inner closure as it will already have a weak reference to self. On the other hand if your outer closure is not using `[weak self]` it is reasonable to put it for the inside block. A more detailed explation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992442/7119329).

Answer (score 0):

The safest approach is to use `[weak self]` 2 times in both outter and inner closure.

There is edge case, where using `[weak self]` 1 time will cause memory leak.

Consider the following escaping closure case, which keeps reference to closures (Example copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62352667/72437)

```
import UIKit

public class CaptureListExperiment {

    public init() {

    }

    var _someFunctionWithTrailingClosure: (() -> ())?
    var _anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure: (() -> ())?

    func someFunctionWithTrailingClosure(closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("starting someFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        _someFunctionWithTrailingClosure = closure

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            self?._someFunctionWithTrailingClosure!()
            print("finishing someFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        }
    }

    func anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure(closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("starting anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        _anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure = closure

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            self?._anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure!()
            print("finishing anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure")
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("doSomething")
    }

    public func testCompletionHandlers() {
        someFunctionWithTrailingClosure { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure {
                self.doSomething()
            }
        }
    }

    // go ahead and add `deinit`, so I can see when this is deallocated

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

func performExperiment() {

    let obj = CaptureListExperiment()

    obj.testCompletionHandlers()
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.3)
}

performExperiment()

/* Output:

starting someFunctionWithTrailingClosure
starting anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure
finishing someFunctionWithTrailingClosure
doSomething
finishing anotherFunctionWithTrailingClosure
*/
```

Since, this kind of edge case is very hard to spot. I think using `[weak self]` 2 times, will be the safest approach and common pattern, without causing developer much headache.